# Речь и река. Этимология

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

"Речь", "изрекать" и "река" — общее ли происхождение у этих слов?

Answer (score 6):

Речь, изрекать — общее. Сущ. **речь** (язык, слово) и глагол **речь** (говорить) — это омоформы, восходящие к и.е. корню *re-. Омонимами были уже в др.-р. Сущ. — от др.-р. сущ. **речь** (слово). В праслав. "речь" (язык, слово, вещь). Глагол — от глагола "речи" (сказывать). В праслав. было *ректи*. От сущ. образовались речевой, речистый, наречие (оба омонима), от глагола — изречь, изрекать, наречь, нарекать, обречь, обрекать, предрекать.

Река — другой корень — из др.-р. **река** (водный поток), кот. восходит к и.е. корню *rei (течь, стремиться). Этот корень мы находим в словах реять, рой, роиться, ринуться (такие звуковые варианты возникли на славянской почве.)

Answer (score 0):

**Река-речка-реченька-речь-речистый-речение-изрёк-рекло**(слово)

Как **рек**а легко переходит в **реч**ку
Так и **реч**ь легко переходит **рек**у(говорю).

В славянский языках река пишется и через **ч** и через **к** и через **ц**. Скорее всего в более древнее время был общий им звук.

Так что ответ на вопрос: Да.

Answer (score -2):

Нет. В "реке" к - корневое (вернее говоря: очень древний суффикс, не идентичный соременному -К-), Ч возникает только в силу палатализации в некоторых формах ("речной", "речка").

В "Речь" всегда Ч (во всех славянских) - и тоже от корня.

А вообще по Фасмеру:

река́ мн. ре́ки, укр. рiка́, др.-русск., ст.-слав. рѣка ποταμός, κρημνός (Остром., Супр.), болг. река́, сербохорв. риjѐка, мн. ри̏jеке̑, словен. rẹ́ka, чеш. řеkа, слвц. rieka, польск. rzeka, в.-луж., н.-луж. rěka, полаб. rė́ka. Родственно рой, ри́нуть(ся), ре́ять. Далее родственно др.-инд. ráуаs м. "течение, ток", rī́уаtē "двигается, начинает течь", rītíṣ ж. "ток, бег", rētas "течение", rīṇas "текущий", галльск. Rēnos "Рейн", ср.-ирл. rían "река, дорога", лат. rīvus м. " ручей, канава", др.-ирл. riathor "torrens", алб.-гег. ritë "влажный, мокрый" (Иокль, Stud. 74), др.-англ. ríđ м., ж. " ручей, река", англ. диал. rithe, ср.-нж.-нем. rîn "ток воды"; см. Траутман, ВSW 243; Хольтхаузен, Aengl. Wb. 262; Шпехт 63, 201; Мейе–Эрну 1014 и сл.; Вальде–Гофм. 2, 437. Менее убедительно сравнение с д.-в.-н. rîgа "ряд", ср.-в.-н. rîhе – то же, др.-инд. rēkhā ж. "ряд, полоса, царапина", вопреки Уленбеку (Aind. Wb. 253), Цупице (GG 137). •• [См. еще Мартине, "Word", 12, 1956, стр. 3. – Т.]

Речь, ж., род. п. -и, укр. рiч, ре́чи, блр. реч " вещь", др.-русск., ст.-слав. рѣчь ῥῆμα, λόγος, διάνοια (Клоц., Супр.), болг. реч, сербохорв. ри̏jеч "слово", словен. rе̣̑č, род. п. -ȋ " вещь", чеш. řеč " речь", слвц. rеč – то же, польск. rzесz " вещь", в.-луж. rěč " речь, язык", н.-луж. rěс – то же. Удлиненная ступень от реку́, рок (см.). Ср. тохар. А rаkе, В reki "слово"; см. Лиден, Kuhn-Festschr. 142; Мейе–Вайан 507. Знач. " предмет, вещь" у Куракина (Смирнов 265), вероятно, объясняется влиянием польск. rzecz; см. также Прусик, KZ 35, 597.